# How can I disable the prompt to run programs for my digital audio player's memory card?

Tags: automount

When I plug in my digital audio player two prompts to run programs appear simultaneously:

[image: screenshot]

How can I disable the prompt for the player's memory card so that only one prompt is displayed?

Comment: You might want to file a bug report about this, it should be possible for the system to detect this situation.  (And I don't have an immediate solution for this, except maybe hiding the memory card completely with udev, which is probably not what you want.)

Comment: Good thought. Any idea what package I should file it against?

Comment: This should be filed as a bug against nautilus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, there is nothing you can do. Nautilus doesn't have the functionality to recognize that there are two storage devices in one player.

As a workaround you can go to the nautilus settings and edit them so that no prompt at all is displayed. You still have the option to open the default media player by right-clicking on the device-icon.